# randomly generate teams from a list of names

Tags: python, class, random

I want to write a program to partition a list of names equally into a dictionary of names and their teams and the problem is I don't know how to distribute team_list to players

```
import random
team_list = ['A', 'B']
players = ['Hosein', 'Maziar', 'Akbar', 'Nima', 'Mehdi', 'Farhad', 'Mohamad', 'Khashayar', 'Milad', 'Mostafa',
                         'Amin', 'Saeed', 'Pooya', 'Pooria', 'Reza', 'Ali', 'Behzad', 'Soheil', 'Behrooz', 'Shahrooz', 'Saman', 'Mohsen']

def team(player_list):
    random.shuffle(player_list)
    return [player_list[i::2] for i in range(2)]

print(team(players))
```

Comment: First, you need to explain how you will represent a team in your program, and then you need to explain what it means to put a player on that team. But the code you wrote to describe Human already doesn't make any sense. I think you need to follow a tutorial more closely, and try to think more carefully about your logic.

Comment: I want to print names and their teams , and teams have no attributes at all

Comment: Could start by actually making a dictionary in the first place, have teams as keys and keep a list of players as values which you could fill by an iteration.

Comment: maybe `teams = dict()` `teams["A"] = player_list[0::2]` `teams["B"] = player_list[1::2]`  ?

Comment: you create lists with names, not dictionares. To create dictionares you would need `{name:"A" for name in player_list[0::2]}` and `{name:"B" for name in player_list[1::2]}`

Comment: No , it doesn't work like that, it should be generated randomly

Comment: but values in `player_list` are random so they are assigned to teams randomly - but I keep them in dictionary in order: first `"A"` and later `"B"`

Comment: I dont want to assign names and teams , the program should do that

Comment: I don't understand what you want - in my answer program assigns names to teams and teams to names automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what result you expect but I see two posible versions

Dictionary with `teams`

```
teams = dict()

teams["A"] = player_list[0::2]
teams["B"] = player_list[1::2]

for team, names in teams.items():
    print(team, names)
```

Result

```
A ['Nima', 'Shahrooz', 'Pooya', 'Mehdi', 'Behzad', 'Maziar', 'Saeed', 'Mostafa', 'Akbar', 'Reza', 'Behrooz']
B ['Ali', 'Mohamad', 'Pooria', 'Milad', 'Hosein', 'Saman', 'Farhad', 'Mohsen', 'Soheil', 'Amin', 'Khashayar']
```

Dictionary with `players`

```
players = dict()

for i, team in enumerate(team_list):
    for name in player_list[i::2]:
        players[name] = team
```

Result:

names as assigned to teams randomly but dictionary keeps them in order: first all random names for `"A"` and later all random names for `"B"`

```
Nima A
Shahrooz A
Pooya A
Mehdi A
Behzad A
Maziar A
Saeed A
Mostafa A
Akbar A
Reza A
Behrooz A
Ali B
Mohamad B
Pooria B
Milad B
Hosein B
Saman B
Farhad B
Mohsen B
Soheil B
Amin B
Khashayar B
```

---

Full working code:

```
import random

team_list   = ['A', 'B']

player_list = ['Hosein', 'Maziar', 'Akbar', 'Nima', 'Mehdi', 
               'Farhad', 'Mohamad', 'Khashayar', 'Milad', 'Mostafa', 
               'Amin', 'Saeed', 'Pooya', 'Pooria', 'Reza', 
               'Ali', 'Behzad', 'Soheil', 'Behrooz', 'Shahrooz', 
               'Saman', 'Mohsen']

random.shuffle(player_list)

print('--- teams ---')

teams = dict()

teams["A"] = player_list[0::2]
teams["B"] = player_list[1::2]

#print(teams)

for team, names in teams.items():
    print(team, names)
    
print('--- players ---')

players = dict()

for i, team in enumerate(team_list):
    for name in player_list[i::2]:
        players[name] = team

#print(players)

for name, team in players.items():
    print(name, team)
```

---

**EDIT:**

I added code which change order in dictionary to keep original order.
But dictionary doesn't have to keep order so I don't know if it makes sense.

I created also list which keeps items `[name, team]` with original order but list is not so useful like dictionary.

```
import random

team_list   = ['A', 'B']

player_list = ['Hosein', 'Maziar', 'Akbar', 'Nima', 'Mehdi', 
               'Farhad', 'Mohamad', 'Khashayar', 'Milad', 'Mostafa', 
               'Amin', 'Saeed', 'Pooya', 'Pooria', 'Reza', 
               'Ali', 'Behzad', 'Soheil', 'Behrooz', 'Shahrooz', 
               'Saman', 'Mohsen']

player_list_random = player_list.copy()   # duplicate to keep original `player_list`
random.shuffle(player_list_random)

print('--- teams ---')

teams = dict()

teams["A"] = player_list_random[0::2]
teams["B"] = player_list_random[1::2]

#print(teams)

for team, names in teams.items():
    print(team, names)
     
print('--- players ---')

players = dict()

for i, team in enumerate(team_list):
    for name in player_list_random[i::2]:
        players[name] = team

players_in_order_dict = dict()
players_in_order_list = list()

# uses original `player_list` to create dict with original order
for name in player_list:
    players_in_order_dict[name] = players[name]
    players_in_order_list.append( [name, players[name]] )
#print(players)

print('- dict -')
for name, team in players_in_order_dict.items():
    print(name, team)

print('- list -')
for name, team in players_in_order_list:
    print(name, team)
```

Comment: I want to generate teams randomly from the list of names

Comment: they are random - I use `random.shuffle(player_list)`. But in dictionary I keep then in order: first random names for `A`, next random names for `B`

Comment: if you want to keep original order from list `player_list` then you will have to use my dictionary with with original `player_list` to create dictionary with different order. But I don't know if this makes send.

Comment: yes , but I want the distribution full randomly and automatically and I dont know how to do that

Comment: the order doesn't matter as well as the form of output , the only thing that matters is being generated randomly and equally

Comment: but my code already does it fully randomly and it does it fully automatically. If you run it few times and compare results then you will see it.

Comment: you assigned the teams to the names

Comment: I don't understand what you want - you have `teams` with player names assigned to team names, and `players` with team names assigned to player names. You have both directions. Maybe show in question what result you expect because I create probably all possible version and I don't understand what you expect.

Comment: look , at first I wanted to write an OOP program with two classes named Human and Player that takes a list of names of 22 person and randomly  generates two teams named 'a' and 'b' but I edited the question to make it more clear . now, I want to write 2 functions that one of them handles making two lists of players and another assigns them to teams and both should be automatically and randomly

Comment: you didn't write it in question so don't expect that we will know what you expect. My code do all want you need and you may need only to put code in functions.

Comment: you're right ,my bad it's better to update the question , thank you anyway